# Cambiar logotipo al hacer scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

Actualmente estoy haciendo una web y el `CMS` `e-commerce` con el que estoy manejando el contenido es `Prestashop` pero me he topado con el siguiente problema:

Tenemos un menú: `X 1 2 3 4`, donde `X` es el logo y los números son secciones del menú.

Al momento de hacer scroll, me gustaría cambiar ese logo y también al momento de subir al tope de la página que vuelva al primer logo.

He estado buscando por la web, cómo agregar código a `Prestashop`, pero no me lo reconoce o mi código esta mal, o ambas. Probé explorando el `JavaScript` que maneja esta propiedad y se me ocurrió esta idea:

Menu : `X 1 2 3 4` estático, y al bajar ocultar la clase que tengo del logo y mostrar una imagen de fondo, que sería el logo que quiero mostrar cuando hago scroll, pero al usar el método `removeClass` no pasa nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el siguiente enlace hay un ejemplo con lo que tú describes:

http://jsfiddle.net/49HA3/255/

Este seria el código del ejemplo:

```js
// esta parte, permite que se ejecute el codigo cuando se halla cargado la pagina
$(function() {
  // esta parte es la que controla cuando se mueve el scroll y ejecuta una función
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    // aca se pregunta si el scroll se movio de pa bajo.
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
      // esta parte cambia el atributo "src" de la etiqueta "img" 
      $('#logo').attr('src', 'http://wowslider.com/images/data/images/slide1.png')
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 1) {
      $('#logo').attr('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#menu {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: auto;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
}

#contenedorMenu {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenedorMenu">
  <img id="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png" width="184" height="60" />
  <ul id="menu">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p style="height:1000px;"></p>
```

Comment: Hola @andrezi Sería mucho más mejor que utilizaras todo el contenido de *jsfiddle* publicado aquí en SO saludos :)

Comment: por favor, me indicas donde leo como lo puedo implementar. Gracias

Comment: Hola @andrezi tu respuesta me fue muy demasiado útil, te lo agradezco Tuve complicaciones siempre pero me fije que no estaba insertando bien el js en el prestashop. Gracias !!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta manipulando este código

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(document).scroll(function(event){
        var position = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
        if(position>150){
           jQuery("#img o .img").replaceWith("<img id='remplazo_nueva_imagen' src='nueva_imagen.jpg' class='clase'>");//id, o clase de tu imagen # =id . = class          
        }else{
          jQuery("#remplazo_nueva_imagen").replaceWith("<img src='' class=''>");  
        }
  });
});
/*
Este codigo lo que hace es detectar el scroll de la pagina en tu caso puedes jugar con los valores y meter el cambio tantas veces que desees, recuerda que para cambiar una imagen en el scroll debes meterle un id, luego para volverla a cambiar usar el mismo id o clase que le pasaste al replaceWith */
/*
OPCION 2*/
/*METER 4 IMAGENES EN UNA MISMA POSICION Y TENERLAS OCULTAS*/

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#img2").hide();
  jQuery("#img3").hide();
  jQuery("#img4").hide();
  jQuery(document).scroll(function(event){
        var position = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
        if(position>50){ 
          jQuery("#img_padre").hide();
          jQuery("#img2").fadeIn(1000);
                if(position>150){ 
                jQuery("#img2").hide();
                jQuery("#img3").fadeIn(1000);
            }
           if(position>250){ 
                jQuery("#img3").hide();
                jQuery("#img4").fadeIn(1000);
            }
        }else{
          jQuery("#img4").hide();
          jQuery("#img_padre").show();
        }
  });
});
/*Detecta cada posicion y va ocultando las imagenes y mostrando otras*/
/*Juega con los valores*/
```